# What calculation is this line making?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was reading through an article about BSP (Binary space partitioning) because I am looking to implement it into my project. I came across this line of code:

```
let max:Int = (splitH ? height : width) - Int(min)
```

Where splitH is a Boolean value and height/width are integers. What is this line doing? What calculation is it making? I have never seen anything like this in swift.

More specifically, what is this operation: `(splitH ? height : width)`

Comment: Search for “ternary conditional operator” in https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `splitH` is true, it picks `height` otherwise it picks `width`, and then subtracts the value `Int(min)` from the picked value.

Its usual syntax is `conditional` ? `statement if conditional is true` : `statement if conditional is false`

Comment: Thats so handy! How have I never heard of this before!

Comment: Happy to help. Definitely check out the link that MartinR posted. You can even use these in nested way :D